# SOAP UI Automation - Assertion if reponse XML's dynamic elements value is blank

Tags: xslt, soap, automation, xquery, soapui

Please find below sample soap request

```
<FlowerSearchRequest>
    <Request>
        <name>ROSE</name>
        <color></color>
        <smell></smell>
    </Request>
</FlowerSearchRequest>
```

**Current Functionality**

1. `<Request>`--`<name>` is mandatory field
2. `<Request>`--`<color>` and `<Request>`--`<smell>` is not mandatory i.e, they can be blank(`<smell></smell>`) but cannot be null
3. SOAP response `<FlowerSearchResponse>` contains all the request parameters `<Request>` and the response parameters for this request under `<ResponseList>` (as shown below)
4. For each `<Request>`,  Response can have List of `<Response>` elements under  `<ResponseList>`
5. If i search with `ROSE` , for few results `<Response>` -- `<smell>` element may/may not have value (but it cannot be null)
6. `<Response>` occurrence in result is dynamic , i.e, if I search with `Lily` I may get 10 or even more `<Response>` elements

SOAP response for above request

```
<FlowerSearchResponse>
    <Request>
        <name>ROSE</name>
        <color></color>
        <smell></smell>
    </Request>
    <ResponseList>
        <Response>
            <name>ROSE</name>
            <color>Red</color>
            <smell>Pleasant</smell>
        </Response>
        <Response>
            <name>ROSE</name>
            <color>Blue</color>
            <smell>UnPleasant</smell>
        </Response>
        <Response>
            <name>ROSE</name>
            <color>Yellow</color>
            <smell></smell>
        </Response>
    </ResponseList>
</FlowerSearchResponse>
```

**Question**

In SOAP UI, how to automate below case?

- Go through all the `<Response>` elements from the dynamic list (not sure about the count of `<Response>` tags at the time of writing assertions), Assert if even a single `<Response>` has Blank value for `<smell>` element
- Assertion test case should only consider elements **`<Response>`**-- `<smell>` when its checking for Blank `<smell>` elements i.e, it should not consider the **`<Request>`** -- `<smell>`

P.S: I am really novice at SOAP UI assertions-- trying hard to find a solution using `xslt`, but couldn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an XPath expression returning true or false depending on whether there is any `Response/smell` element with no content:

```
(: returns true if NO single one smell element is empty :)
empty(//Response/smell[empty(node())])
```

If you want to count them instead:

```
(: returns the number of empty smell elements :)
count(//Response/smell[empty(node())])
```